# signalR script reference?

Tags: signalr

All the signalR examples shows

`<script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>`

without explainning enough what is it used for .

For the Html page it is a location of folder . and there is no script there.

Why and how this line is being used ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The /signalr/hubs page is a JavaScript file that is auto generated by SignalR which contains generated hub proxies for every hub in your SignalR project.

For instance (got this from http://shootr.signalr.net/signalr/hubs) lets take a look at the code snippet.

```
    proxies.h = this.createHubProxy('h'); 
            proxies.h.client = { };
            proxies.h.server = {
                changeViewport: function (viewportWidth, viewportHeight) {
                    return proxies.h.invoke.apply(proxies.h, $.merge(["changeViewport"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
                 },

                fire: function () {
                    return proxies.h.invoke.apply(proxies.h, $.merge(["fire"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
                 },        
...
```

"this" refers to the hub connection, or rather $.connection.hub.  So we're essentially saying proxies.h = $.connection.hub.createHubProxy('h');

Now 'h' is a hub on the server See https://github.com/NTaylorMullen/ShootR/blob/master/ShootR/ShootR/Server/GameHub.cs, more specifically look at the hub name attribute.

Next we have proxies.h.client; this is the endpoint for where users are able to declare their client side functions that will be invoked from the server.

We then have proxies.h.server, this references all the public hub methods on the GameHub.cs.  So some of the functions are changeViewport, and fire.  This code is auto generated on the server to represent each of your hubs.

Lastly at the end of the signalr/hubs file we extend all of the dynamically created hubs onto the $.connection object so users can then access them via

```
var myGameHub = $.connection.h;
```

Hope this helps!